# R Keras: Convert tensorflow tensor to R array

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am using R Keras. I can obtain the output of an intermediate layer by for example executing:

```
layer_output <- get_layer(mymodel, index=1)$output
```

where mymodel is a Keras model.
The problem is that layer_output is a tensor.

```
class(layer_output)

    [1] "tensorflow.tensor" "tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor"     
    [3] "tensorflow.python.framework.ops._TensorLike" "python.builtin.object"
```

I want to convert layer_output to an R object such as an array or matrix, but I can't find a way to do it. Many thanks if you can advise me.

Comment: Such conversion is not possible, you can only get a layer output if you give an input. What exactly are you trying to do with the result?

Comment: I want to use the result for a clustering application. I think Makeyourownmaker's response below gives me what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a new model which will only output your layer of interest.

First create the original model:

```
model <- ...  # create original model
```

Then create the new model and use predict to get the output:

```
layer_name <- 'my_layer'
intermediate_layer_model <- keras_model(inputs = model$input,
                                        outputs = get_layer(model, layer_name)$output)
intermediate_output <- predict(intermediate_layer_model, data)
```

Depending on your model the R keras predict function should return a vector, matrix or array - instead of the layer instance returned by get_layer.

Comment: Aha! That appears to work. I am getting the shape I expected. Thanks.