# How to convert a tensor to an R array (in a loss function, so without eager execution)?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I have `TensorFlow` version 2.4 and work with the R packages `tensorflow` (2.2.0) and `keras` (2.3.0.0.9000).
I would like to convert tensors to R arrays in a loss function (don't ask why).
Here is an example when such a conversion (outside a loss function) works:

```
library(tensorflow)
library(keras)
x.R <- matrix(1:12, ncol = 3) # dummy R object
x.tensor <- keras_array(x.R) # converting the R object to a tensor
as.array(x.tensor) # converting it back to an R array. This works because...
stopifnot(tf$executing_eagerly()) # ... eager execution is enabled
```

During training of a model, eager execution is `FALSE` though and thus
the `as.array()` call fails. To see this, let's first define a dummy
neural network model and training data.

```
d <- 2 # input and output dimension
in.lay  <- layer_input(shape = d)
hid.lay <- layer_dense(in.lay,  units = 300, activation = "relu")
out.lay <- layer_dense(hid.lay, units = d,   activation = "sigmoid")
model <- keras_model(in.lay, out.lay)
n <- 1200 # number of training samples
data <- matrix(runif(n * d), ncol = d) # training data
```

Now let's define the loss function and compile the model with it.

```
myloss <- function(x, y) { # x and y are tensors here
   stopifnot(!tf$executing_eagerly()) # confirms that eager execution is disabled
   x. <- as.array(x) # ... fails with "RuntimeError: Evaluation error: invalid first argument, must be vector (list or atomic)." How can we convert x to an R array?
   loss_mean_squared_error(x, y) # just a dummy return value (the MSE)
}
compile(model, optimizer = "adam", loss = myloss)
```

Let's try and fit this model (to see that it fails to convert the tensor `x` to an R array via `as.array()`).

```
prior <- matrix(rexp(n * d), ncol = d) # input sample to train the NN on
n.epoch <- 5 # number of epochs to train
batch.size <- 400 # batch size
fit(model, x = prior, y = data, batch_size = batch.size, epochs = n.epoch) # fails with error message given above
```

The R package tensorflow provides `tfe_enable_eager_execution()` to enable eager execution
in a session. But if I call it with `TensorFlow` 2.4, then I obtain:

```
tfe_enable_eager_execution() # "Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) :  AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'"
```

Ideally, I wouldn't want to mess with eager execution much (not sure about the side effects),
just converting a tensor to an array. My guess is that there is no other way than eager execution as
only then the pointers are resolved and the R package `tensorflow` finds the data
in the tensor and is able to convert it to an array.

Other ideas to enable/disable eager execution are mentioned [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64433/symbolicexception-inputs-to-eager-execution-function-cannot-be-keras-symbolic-t/80599#80599) but that's all in Python
and not available in R it seems. And this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918337/r-keras-convert-tensorflow-tensor-to-r-array) post seems to ask the same question but in a different context.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I suspect it is not possible. I think the loss function has to be implemented on Tensorflow tensors (e.g. using tf$* methods from R), because then Tensorflow can (sometimes) autogenerate a gradient function that goes with the loss, which is need for optimization. I'm not sure, though, and would love more input on this.

Comment: No, otherwise I would have posted a solution. I'd also like to have more input on this (and many other things concerning R's keras, for example why it doesn't respect R's set.seed() function and other things).

Comment: It doesn't respect the set.seed() function because it is only an interface to access a Python library. So you need to set the seed for the Python session. I think you can do that using the use_session_with_seed() function in the tensorflow package. But note that it won't work if you're doing parallel computations.